# C++ Extracting Zip File using Powershell Command

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, cmd, command

I'm trying to extract a zip file to a folder within my C++ program. I don't want to use any external libraries or dependencies.

To do this, I'm issuing a CMD command from my C++ program to execute powershell. So, I execute a system command, which activates poweshell, which extracts the zip file.

Here's my code:

```
string extractCommand = "powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command \"& { Add - Type - A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('\"C:/Users/Eyesight Technology/Desktop/data/somsearch.zip/\"', '\"C:/Users/Eyesight Technology/Desktop\"'); }\"";
        system(extractCommand.c_str());
```

I think the problem may be in the usage of quotes and escape characters, though I am not sure. I have tried running the command from the command line directly (with no escape keys, obviously) and it works like a charm! But in C++ with the escape keys, I get errors from powershell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Output the string if you're not sure whether its content with all the escaping is right.

Comment: "I don't want to use any external libraries or dependencies" ... "I'm issuing a CMD command from my C++ program to execute powershell" - for someone who does not want any dependencies I'm surprised at what you are doing. You have *multiple* dependencies already; 1) Windows. 2) cmd. 3) powershell. 4) whatever enables powershell to extract zip files.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - I think the OP does not want to depend on anything that is not already on the machine. No new toys. Oh, I mean tools.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That is exactly what I mean. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell 5, use `Expand-Archive`.

```
Expand-Archive -Path 'C:/Users/Eyesight Technology/Desktop/data/somsearch.zip' `
    -DestinationPath 'C:/Users/Eyesight Technology/Desktop'
```